# Using subtitles in Rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following the rails guide for setting up a blog. I want to have subtitles in my post and I can't figure out how to add subtitles using a form. Is there a helper for this and if not how/where do I define my own?

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: you need to add new field database migration and in controller you have to permit that field and at view side you need to add input box

Comment: When I tried I get a undefined method `sub_title' error

Comment: can you show me code what you tried?

Comment: class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.string :sub_title_1
      

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Comment: Then in the controller I added     def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :sub_title_1)
    end

Comment: you need to add new field in migration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115670/discussion-between-cameron-hall-and-uzaif).

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment, but according to your comment, you get an undefined method error for 'sub_title', but in your migration you have named the column 'sub_title_1'. 
It would appear this is a naming issue. 
Either change your migration file to create a column called 'sub_title' and not 'sub_title_1', or in your form, use 'f.text_field :sub_title_1' instead of 'f.text_field :sub_title'

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Now I get "undefined method error for 'sub_title_1'"

Comment: which did you do? change the migration or change the form?

Comment: I tried both. That wasn't the problem. as uzaif suggest I ran rails generate migration add_fieldname_to_tablename fieldname:string
replace your data in above command and that worked

Comment: okay, but just adding a new migration to add the field for sub_title when you already have a field sub_title_1 and your strong params are only permitting sub_title_1 sounds like you may now have two fields: sub_title and sub_title_1 and have them being used in seperate places which will quite possibly give you unwanted results in terms of what is being set and retrieved where, so be sure to make sure you have only the one field and are only ever calling the one field in your code. Other than that im glad you got it working and good luck with setting up your blog.